# Decorating a HashMap adding randomness to prevent (D)DoS

Tags: java, php, hashmap, denial-of-service

**EDIT** *by the way the point of the workaround here is to reuse all the existing HashMap (like the ConcurrentHashMap etc.) instead of re-inventing entirely the wheel.  Languages using randomized hash functions (like Perl) are protected against this attack.*

In the light of the very recent and devastating DDoS using known flaw in several hashmap implementations (known to affect Java webservers, but also PHP and others), Apache Tomcat just came out with a "fix" in the form of a patch allowing to put a cap on the maximum allowed numbers of parameters in a POST request (patch your Tomcat to 6.0.35+ or 7.0.23+ btw).

The (D)DoS is apparently basically using the fact that strings can be crafted so that they do collide when hashed and that a lot of webservers "stupidly" put key/value parameters in (broken) hashmaps.

I was wondering if it would be possible to write a decorator around a HashMap{String,String} so that to every String added a random (random from the point of view of an attacked) value was added to the String, like this:

```
... get( String s ) {
    return wrappedBrokenMap.get( s + crunch(s );
}

... put( String key, String value ) {


  wrappedBrokenMap.put( s + crunch(s), value );
}
```

And here would be one implementation of *crunch(...)* (it is just an example, the point is: the attacker doesn't know the implementation):

```
private static final int MY_MAGICAL_NUMBER = 0x42BABE;  // attacker doesn't know that number

private static String crunch( String s ) {
    return s.length + "" + MY_MAGICAL_NUMBER;
}
```

If for any String s *crunch(s)* returns a reproducible String that the attacker cannot guess, the DDoS attack has effectively been prevented right?

Would that work?

Comment: Instead of using a hardcoded number which always has its problems (open sourcing the code gets.. "interesting" at least), why not use `System.milliSeconds()` at startup instead. Seems like the simplest solution as long as hashmaps aren't serialized.

Comment: Do you have a link for that attack?  I don't quite understand since when there is a collision, it is resolved.  I think Java uses a linked list for colliding buckets.

Comment: @toto2 Ancient attack really, but there's been some media now - [ars article](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2011/12/huge-portions-of-web-vulnerable-to-hashing-denial-of-service-attack.ars). The thing is: If you put millions of objects into a map whose keys all map to the same bucket, you get the performance of a linked list where you always insert at the end (i.e. O(n) insert and lookup).

Comment: @Voo Thanks.  So each server instance needs its own hash function.

Comment: @toto2: Here, it is really bad: http://cryptanalysis.eu/blog/2011/12/28/effective-dos-attacks-against-web-application-plattforms-hashdos/

Comment: @toto You can do it per request actually - as I understand it it's only used for the request values itself.

Comment: @Voo If you modify each request the same way on your server, it's the same as having a different hash function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If for any String s *crunch(s)* returns a reproducible String that the attacker cannot guess, the DDoS attack has effectively been prevented right?

Basically, this is what you do when you salt password hashes (although for slightly different reasons). It doesn't *prevent* collision attacks entirely (if you have a hash function mapping arbitrary-length input to a fixed-length output, hashes can always collide), but using a secret salt should make such attacks harder.

A quick'n'dirty implementation could look something like this:

```
public class SaltedHashMap<V> {
    private final Map<String, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    private final String salt;
    public SaltedHashMap(String salt) {
        this.salt = salt;
    }
    public V get(String key){
        return map.get(key + salt);
    }
    public void put(String key, V value) {
        map.put(key + salt, value);
    }
}
```

Using a web server as an example, we could use a `SecureRandom` to randomize a new salt for every incoming request, meaning that even if you managed to figure out a collision-generating input for one request, it would be extremely unlikely to work for other requests.

Comment: I really don't see the similarity between salts and this. a) salts need not be secret to work and b) we have only one secret key for the whole hashmap not per object. If we want the cryptography comparison it's more like a private key: Without it you can't do anything and if your attacker gets it you've lost.

Comment: The similarity to a salted password is that we add something to our inputs to avoid predictable hashes. Although I agree it's more of a technical similarity than a conceptual similarity (in which case your key analogy is better).

Comment: @gustafc: +1...  I edited my question to reflect the fact that of course I want a "workaround" so I can using the great APIs Java has like ConcurrentHashMap etc.  I love your SaltedHashMap idea: instead of using a salt "per application" it would be "per hashmap".  Very, very nice!

Comment: @gustaf Fair enough, you can see it that way too. Your answer is still perfectly valid, it was just the terminology :)

Answer (score 1):

The alternative String hash function added in 7u6 has been removed from JDK 8, along with the jdk.map.althashing.threshold system property. Instead, hash bins containing a large number of colliding keys improve performance by storing their entries in a balanced tree instead of a linked list. This JDK 8 change applies only to HashMap, LinkedHashMap, and ConcurrentHashMap.

Please refer: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes8.html

Answer (score 0):

I think by the time it gets to your code (where you could make the above changes), the hashing has already been done by the underlying libraries that handle the POST request. So, no, I don't think it would work.

Comment: That's a very valid point but I was more thinking of a workaround for the people using the hashmap (apparently Oracle ain't going to "fix" their hashmap so every webserver out there will have to patch soon).

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee the change is global, I would create a patched String like with a method like this

```
// from java.lang.String
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && count > 0) {
        h = MY_STARTING_VALUE;
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;
        int len = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = MY_PRIME*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

The problem with this is that some libraries rely on the implementation of hashCode being a particular way.  If you are not using such a library, this guarantees that every piece of code using Strings will be patched.

---

The problem with using a "crush" or seed is that you need to know its value to perform the lookup in the first place. If you use a random value, you have to poll every possible key to get out a value which doesn't sound very efficient.

If you are worried about the worst case performance, you can use TreeMap. It's typical and worst case performance is O(log n) to perform an insert/lookup.

---

If you are really worried about this you could use a String class with your own hashCode() or you could override the built in hashCode for String or the value used by HashMap.

Comment: Huh? If you want to look up something in a hashmap you need the key. If you have the key, you can crunch it - where's the problem? He can just do a simple `key = crunch(key)` for a general solution before adding/searching the array in his class.

Comment: It depends on whether you want it to be random or not. Random would be harder to predict, but also harder for you to predict.  If you want to add a seed to the key it should work, but its not that random.

Comment: The OP uses a `static final` value.  It's not that random, but at least it would repel a "standard" attack (if they even exist).

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I'm not worried.  The entire industry is.  Apache has already patched Tomcat.  PHP has already been patched.  Microsoft is releasing today a patch (instead of tuesday) to fix this.  A single machine can take down a server farm made of 10 000 CPUs.  There are reasons to be worried ; )

Comment: @Peter Well we'd have to store the value with the HashMap in any case so I don't think it's much of a problem. Just use a static RandomGenerator and generate a new value for each hashmap or use timestamps and we're good to go - timestamps would work fine too I think. I can think of some problems but it'd be certainly quite hard to exploit in such a case.