# Why hash function doesnt use randomness?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I read in [CLRS](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) that good hash function is: `h(x) = ((a*x + b)mod p) mod m`
where `a,b` random, `p` prime, `m` table size

I cannot find this hash function in any libraries in any programming language, especially in Java. Why?
I'm talking about implementations for hashCode.

Comment: As others mentioned, we don't know if you're talking about cryptographic hashes or implementations for `hashCode`. The latter have no need for randomness.

Comment: @LewBloch updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming you mean "hash" as in "hash table/hash map" and not in the sense of cryptographic hashes like SHA1)

Modern best practice in hash design actually *does* involve randomness in order to prevent denial-of-service attacks caused by people feeding in input that all hashes to the same value.  [Python, for example, does this since version 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__), and I believe recent versions of Perl do as well; see also: http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html

Comment: Thanks, that's mean that all Java apps can be hacked because they don't have defense from denial-of-service attacks?

Comment: @ipetr No, there are other protection possibilities.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35850674/581205

Answer (score 2):

Ok, both answers missed the mark. jwodder talks about salting hashes with random salts, and Juan talks about something else entirely.

The hash function you talk about does have random a and b, but it only gets the random a,b once. Then uses the same values for those through the lifetime of your data. Otherwise you could end up with a scenario where the same value has different hashes and no salt to distinguish why they're different.

The hash you listed is good for randomly distributing values into buckets, as needed by a hash table. The hash functions you see in java however, would be cryptographic, used for integrity and authentication. Alternatively, if you're actually investigating the code used for hash tables, you may see random values a and b, but they would just be constants at that point, they were randomly generated before being added to the library.

Comment: Why do you say I am talking about something different? In what regards to the function itself a an b are two constants which could or not be chosen randomly. And besides of the clarification about java your are saying the same thing with other words.

Comment: you explained what a hashing function does, not why there are random numbers in the formula

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good hash function in some cases, but it'd be a terrible `hashCode` implementation. Java `hashCode` is supposed to return an arbitrary `int`, so constraining it via `mod p` and `mod m` makes no sense.

In a hash table like `java.util.HashMap`, the table size is always a power of two, which allows using bitwise AND instead of the slow modulus computation. Actually, non power of two tables get hardly ever used because of speed.

Using arbitrary random `a` and `b` in your formula is surely wrong. Using `a==0` is a full scale disaster and so is `a==p` or `a==m`. Using `a==0x80000000` is only slightly better and there are many other really bad values of `a`.

Note that using b` is just wasting time, especially it adds no hash dos protection. While it makes the hash value unpredictable, it preserved all collisions.

Answer (score -1):

A hash doesn't need to be random, its target would be to provide an even distribution amongst a limited range of possible results based on random input.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that your input will be random

Comment: By random I meant "not ordered".  And it is not a requirement.

Comment: If randomness is not required, why would it be included in what is described as a "good" hash function as per the referenced book?

Comment: I guess the book must be refering to the randomness of the output of the hash function which would provide the even distribution I mentioned. The randomnes I mentioned is regarding the inputs to the hash function.

Comment: `h(x) = ((a*x + b)mod p) mod m` That appears to be a function where the input to `h` is `x`. I don't see how it could be referencing the output in any way.

Comment: x is the input and h(x) is the output. x can take any value but h(x) will be constrained betwee 0 and m due to last 'mod' m of the function. The idea of the hash function is that given an unordered (random) input of x values it will generate an evenly distributed set of 0 to m values for h(x). Evenly distributed could be rephrased as random.

Comment: "Evenly distributed" and "random" are not synonyms. The number sequence `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` is evenly distributed among the whole numbers less than `10`, but it is not random. I picked the order. it doesn't even "look random". The `hashCode` for `Integer` returns the enclosed `int`. That isn't random, but it is a darned good hash code. You cannot legitimately claim that "[e]venly distributed could be rephrased as random".

Comment: Lew Bloch, I agree with you they are not synoyms, but your are putting my comment out of context. In my previous comment I refered to the even distribution provided by a random function. If the function being used generates random numbers in a given interval, it also provides an even distribution of them otherwise they wouldn't be random (or pseudorandom). For hash functions (in the context of the formula presented in this question) you don't need randomness you do need even distribution to minimize the number of collisions.

Comment: @LewBloch sorry I didn't tag you correctly yesterday.